# CSS mask image issue

Tags: css

I'm trying to mask some text with a striped image. When i inspect the element i can see the mask image but it will not work. Link below.

http://piersrueb.com/colors/

I got the code from the Trent Walton site, the strange this is that if i copy the image path from Trent's site and place it in my css it works.

http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/

If you can tell me where i am going wrong I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask images have to be monochrome. Colours inside of them will have no effect.

Comment: Don't think so... I'm working from memory here, but I'm sure I've used photos before.

Comment: Hmm, I think colours and partial transparency are only supported for SVG images, no?

Answer (score 1):

It is something to do with your PNG. I'm not really sure why, but I quickly swapped out your http://piersrueb.com/colors/img/stripes.png for Trent's http://trentwalton.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/mask.png using Chrome's web inspector and it started working.

I couldn't tell you why this is happening, perhaps some weird image meta? But I hope that helps you figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking this :-

http://jsfiddle.net/rD6wq/18/

you can use  css3 property **-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;** for transparent text &
   **-webkit-background-clip: text;** for call the bg image in text clip....

but these properties only support for web-kit browsers.....

**HTML**

```
<p>R</p>

<p>T</p>

<p>SUPER</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p{
    font-size:5em;
    font-family:impact;
    background: url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7245/7086291447_06484c1d6a_z.jpg) fixed; 
position:relative;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;        
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}
p:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
body{
    background: url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7245/7086291447_06484c1d6a_z.jpg)  fixed;
}
```

​

Comment: Thanks, I might give this a go.